# perl - extract substring to a character with count zero or more

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have the following strings in a file

```
1. aaa bbb zccc ddd eee; 
2. yyaaa bbb zccc dzdd eee;  ('z' is present multiple times)
3. yyaaa bbb ccc *zddd eee;  (special character '*' present)
4. yyaaa bbb ccc * zddd eee; (special character '*' present)
5. aaa bbb ccc* zddd eee;    (special character '*' present)
6. aaa bbb ccc ddd eee;      ('z' is absent)
```

Another example file

```
1. aaa bbb zccc ddd eee; 
2. yyaaa bbb zccc dzdd eee;
3. yyaaa bbb *ccc * zddd eee;
4. yyaaa bbb * ccc zddd eee;
5. aaa bbb* ccc zddd eee;
6. aaa bbb ccc ddd eee;
```

In each line, I want to extract the substring from the end of `aaa` to the first presence of `z` (minus the `z`). If `z` is absent, it should print the whole string. If there are special characters it should omit them.

REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
bbb
bbb
bbb ccc
bbb ccc
bbb ccc
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't give the output I am seeking

```
my $file = qq(test.txt);
open (my $IN, '<', $file) || die "Cannot open $file for read: $!";     
my @lines=<$IN>;  
close($IN);

foreach (@lines)
{
    if( $_ =~ m/aaa\b(.*?)z/)
    {
        print "$1\n";
    } 
}
```

MY OUTPUT

```
bbb
bbb
bbb ccc *
bbb ccc *
bbb ccc*
```

I am not sure how to exclude the special character (tried character classes) and it doesn't output anything for line#6 where there is no 'z' character present.

Comment: Maybe `if( $_ =~ m/aaa\b([^z*]*)/)`? Could you please clarify the rules?

Comment: Define "special character". Is it just `*` or are there others?

Comment: For the purpose of this question, it is just `*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negated character class as

```
if( $_ =~ m/aaa\b([^z;]*)/)
{
    $string = $1;
    $string =~ s/\*//g;
    print "$string\n";
}
# Outputs
# bbb
# bbb
# bbb ccc
# bbb ccc
# bbb ccc
# bbb ccc ddd eee
```

- `[^z;]*` Matches anything other than `z` or `;`
- `$string =~ s/\*//g;` substitute `*` in the group with nothing.

Comment: It doesn't work for something like 
    `1. aaa bbb zccc ddd eee; 
    2. yyaaa bbb zccc dzdd eee;
    3. yyaaa bbb *ccc * zddd eee;
    4. yyaaa bbb * ccc zddd eee;
    5. aaa bbb* ccc zddd eee;
    6. aaa bbb ccc ddd eee;`

Comment: @ontherocks If the `*` can happen between `a` and `z`, we will have to substitute it with null to remove them. I have edited my answer hope it helps

Comment: @ontherocks Glad to hear it worked. Don't know why two poeple choose to downvote.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want

Note that there's no way to excluded the "special" characters in a single capture, so this must be done in two stages

Your "required output" has fewer spaces than the corresponding input line, but you don't mention anything about that in the text, so there's no way of knowing what it is that you really want

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {

    next unless /a+\s+((?:(?!\s*z).)+)/;

    (my $val = $1) =~ tr/*;//d;

    print $val, "\n";
}



__DATA__
1. aaa bbb zccc ddd eee; 
2. yyaaa bbb zccc dzdd eee;
3. yyaaa bbb *ccc * zddd eee;
4. yyaaa bbb * ccc zddd eee;
5. aaa bbb* ccc zddd eee;
6. aaa bbb ccc ddd eee;
```

#### output

```
bbb
bbb
bbb ccc 
bbb  ccc
bbb ccc
bbb ccc ddd eee
```

Comment: Can we get rid of the semicolon in the last line in the output?

Comment: @ontherocks: Done. You really need to learn to specify your requirement accurately. It's not fair to make people who are helping you for free run around adding "just one more thing" over and over again.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Can you please explain the nested grouping for extraction?

Comment: @ontherocks: That's highly ironic given my last comment about "just one more thing"